# Can I take an exponent out of a sum?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, logarithms

For example, assuming we had a sum:

$$\sum_{n=1}^m n^b \quad m,b\in\mathbb{N}$$

Is there any way to take the $b$ out of the sum?

I tried taking the $\log_n$ of every value, add them together then devide buy how many there are...like so:

**NOTE:** Because $\log_1(1^b)$ can be problematic. I tried not including it and still got the right answer I was looking for.

$$\sum_{n=1}^m {\log_{n+1}((n+1)^b)\over m} = b$$

This works, you can try it.

My problem here though is the fact that there's still a $b$ in the sum.

If I try shift it out, I get:

$$\sum_{n=1}^m {b\log_{n+1}((n+1))\over m} = b$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^m {\log_{n+1}((n+1))\over m} = {b\over b} = 1$$

So here the $b$ is gone. Which again, isn't what I want.

Is there a way to derive a sum from the first sum, that equals $b$ on both sides, in which one side contains no $b$?

I hope the question makes sense.

Comment: We can probably get reasonable *estimates* for $b$, given the sum and $m$. As to closed form, I would expect not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have these identities

$$\sum_{k=1}^n k^0  = n$$

$$\sum_{k=1}^n k^1  = {n(n+1)\over 2}$$

$$\sum_{k=1}^n k^2  = {n(n+1)(2n+1)\over6}$$

$$\sum_{k=1}^n k^3  = {n^2(n+1)^2\over 4}$$

There is quite  bit going on here.  There is no "canonical" rule, but there is a scheme for doing this.  For a discussion of this problem, I recommend Knuth et. al.'s Concrete Mathematics.